# R system() not working with MODIS Reprojection Tool

Tags: r, macos

I have a command that works when typed into the Terminal on a Mac (OSX El Cap), but the same command fails when called from R using `system()`.

I am trying to batch-process MODIS satellite files using the [MODIS Reprojection Tool](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool).  My software is all up to date.

This is a simple example in which I mosaic two files.  The names of the two files are in a text input file called `input.list`.  The command just tells the `mrtmosaic` routine where to find the input list and where to put the output.

This command works correctly in the Terminal:

```
/Applications/Modis_Reprojection_Tool/bin/mrtmosaic -i ~/temp/input.list -o ~/temp/output.hdf
```

However, if I put exactly the same string into a variable and run it from R (using RStudio), it fails:

```
comstring<-"/Applications/Modis_Reprojection_Tool/bin/mrtmosaic -i ~/temp/input.list -o ~/temp/output.hdf"  
system(comstring)
```

> Warning: gctp_call : Environmental Variable Not Found:
>       MRT_DATA_DIR nor MRTDATADIR not defined
>       Error: GetInputGeoCornerMosaic : General Processing Error converting lat/long coordinates to input projection coordinates.
>       Fatal Error, Terminating...

The strange thing is that the system knows what the environment variables are.  In the terminal, the command
`echo $MRT_DATA_DIR`
shows the correct directory: **/Applications/Modis_Reprojection_Tool/data**

I don't see why it would have trouble finding the variables from an `R system()` call when it has no trouble in the Terminal.  I'm very stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this question to the R help list, and two people there helped me solve the problem.  They suggested (if I understood right) that the problem was that OSX El Capitan was not successfully passing environment variables to R.  In any case:

These *do not* work:

1. Setting the environment variable in my `.bash_profile` (for example by adding and exporting `MTR_DATA_DIR="/Applications/MRT/data"`); or
2. Setting the environment variable by adding the same line to the `.Rprofile` file in my home directory.

These *do* work:

3. Setting the environment variable at the R command line by typing `Sys.setenv(MRT_DATA_DIR="/Applications/MRT/data")`; or
4. Setting the environment variable in the `.Renviron` file (which is in my home directory) by adding `MRT_DATA_DIR="/Applications/MRT/data"` to it; or
5. Typing `MRT_DATA_DIR="/Applications/MRT/data" open -a Rstudio` in the Terminal.  This last method is an effective workaround and a useful tool in a bag of tricks, but is slightly clumsier since one has to remember to open RStudio this way  each time.